# How to call a javascript function using a javascript object from a different javascript file?

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

I am currently using a predefined javascript Select2.js.

Now my issue is that I have some set of values that are to be removed from the list which are again dynamic values as in say when I am editing a page and I need the already saved  values again fetched from backend during page load to not appear when I am searching for the data.

For the above I need a way to access the select2 object being created on the page load and set add these values in some attribute but from a different js file.

Can anyone please help me with the same? I hope whatever I am making sense...

Thanks in advance.

Sample code --

```
var val = this.getVal(),
                choices = this.results.find(".select2-result"),
                compound = this.results.find(".select2-result-with-children"),
                self = this;
            choices.each2(function (i, choice) {
                var id = self.id(choice.data("select2-data"));
                if (indexOf(id, val) >= 0) {
                    choice.addClass("select2-selected");
                    // mark all children of the selected parent as selected
                    choice.find(".select2-result-selectable").addClass("select2-selected");
                }
            });
            compound.each2(function(i, choice) {
                // hide an optgroup if it doesnt have any selectable children
                if (!choice.is('.select2-result-selectable')
                    && choice.find(".select2-result-selectable:not(.select2-selected)").length === 0) {
                    choice.addClass("select2-selected");
                }
            });
```

The above is a snippet from the select2.js..

Here this refers to the select2 object being created using the below code :

```
$(".select2Search").select2({
        closeOnSelect: false,
        width: '450px',
         minimumInputLength: 3,
         ajax: {},
        allowClear: true,
        tags: true
    });
```

When alerted, val returns the comma separated ids of the elements already selected so I need to make sure that this.getVal()  has the predefined data...

There is a function named setVal as below -

```
setVal: function (val) {
            var unique;
            if (this.select) {
                this.select.val(val);
            } else {
                unique = [];
                // filter out duplicates
                $(val).each(function () {
                    if (indexOf(this, unique) < 0) unique.push(this);
                });

                this.opts.element.val(unique.length === 0 ? "" : unique.join(this.opts.separator));
                alert(this.opts.element.val());
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you show some example code?

Comment: Added sample code in the question itself

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle